# Open new window when double-click row

Tags: java, jtable, double-click

I would like to open a new window; I plan to modify the data in the last column.

status: The cells are editable;

trigger: I double-click on the select line.

I tried with JOptionPane but the whole table is displayed.

```
       TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel (donnee, titrecolonnes)
            {
            public Class getColumnClass(int columnNames) {
                Class returnValue;
                if ((columnNames >= 0) && (columnNames < getColumnCount())){
                  returnValue = getValueAt(0, columnNames).getClass();
                } else {
                  returnValue = Object.class;
                }
                 return returnValue;
              }
            };
            table = new JTable (model){
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int colonne)
                {
                 return false;
                }
            }; 

            table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){

                public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent e)
             {
                    if((e.getClickCount()%2 == 0))
                    {
                        JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource() ;
                        final int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                        final int colonne = target.getSelectedColumn();
                        String s = table.getModel().getValueAt(
                                    table.getSelectedRow(),table.getSelectedColumn()).toString();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(table));    
                    }
             }

 });
```

Comment: The whole table is displayed because you are passing it (wrapped in a JScrollPane) as the JOptionPane's message.  Instead, pass as your message argument what you actually want to be displayed in the dialog.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I use JOptionPane I can not change the cells.

Comment: Are you asking how to display a dialog without blocking the parent window's input?

Comment: No, my question is when I double click on a line of my table , I want it opens a new window in order to update my table.

Comment: Why is displaying a JOptionPane which contains something other than your table insufficient?